# twitter bootstrap Select box arrow is not displaying in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter bootstrap `select` box arrow is not displaying in Firefox browser. How can I make it visible in iPhone modes?

Here is the normal selectbox coding that I used:

```
<select class="selectbox" id="selection">
    <option>Select category</option>
    <option>General</option>
    <option>Wild</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap there is no `selectbox` class, at least not in the newer versions. You just need to give it the class `form-control`. For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/982TK/)